# Are observable lazy ? Angular 5

Tags: angular, observable, angular2-services

```
 this.postService.delete(ps).subscribe(resp => this.res = resp);
 console.log('result'+this.res);
```

console show result : undefined

does observable are lazy ?

Comment: They are asynchronous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has nothing to do with lazyness. It has to do with **asynchronism**.

You're sending an AJAX request. The first A in AJAX means *asynchronous*. This means that you send the request, and the execution doesn't block until the response comes back. That would freeze the whole application. And even if it did, you would then not have to deal with observables. HttpClient would simply return the response directly.

So, instead, it's asynchronous: you send the request, and continue doing whatever you want while the request is being sent and handled by the server. When the response finally comes back (that can be several seconds later), the browser tells you it's available by invoking a callback function: the one you're passing to `subscribe()`.

You can see that as a toaster: you put your bread in the toaster, and you can keep reading your journal and browse Twitter while the bread is being toasted. You can't start eating your toast until the toaster tells you that the toast is ready.

Answer (score 1):

No, they aren't lazy, but they are **asynchronous**.

Try this:

```
this.postService.delete(ps).subscribe(resp => 
 { 
   this.res = resp;
   console.log('result'+this.res);
 });
```

Comment: `they aren't lazy, but they are asynchronous.` Where did you find it?

Comment: Look at this example http://jsbin.com/tuduwagizi/1/edit?js,console If it was asynchronous then output would be `undefined`

Comment: @yurzui
`An array whose items arrive asynchronously over time. Observables help you manage asynchronous data...`
from https://angular.io/guide/glossary#observable

Comment: They help but are you sure that they are asynchronous?

Comment: I guess I've got to concede that they arent *themselves* async, they're a tool to handle async processes, but dont you think that for example, in the context of this question, its simpler not to delve this deep?